# Intended use for customer_note in tables

Tags: magento2, orders

Whats the intended use for column customer_note that i find in a lot of tables.
Ex qoute, quote_address, sales_invoice, sales_order.

I'm going to add a comment field for customers on checkout, and this seem like an ok field to use instead of adding more fileds to the tables.

I can't find any use in CE but i guess it's used in EE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not used by CE or EE. It is likely kept for legacy reasons.

Many order comment extensions do use that `customer_note` field for storage, so your use case would not be out of the ordinary.

A better place would be the order comments/history, as stored in `sales_order_status_history`. You could use this in place of or in addition to the `customer_note` field. Status history records can be set to display on the order page and even included in emails under certain circumstances, so that might avoid extra work. You just need to save it on the order to start. See `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::addStatusHistory()`.

Comment: I am going with the customer_note field since it seems to be hazzle free (no risk of beeing overwritten by any standard module). And its included everywhere its needed and already transfered from qoute to order without any extra work. Another thing i discovered is that customer_note is copied to sales_order_status_history.

Answer (score 4):

This field **is** used!

`customer_note`

This table field is used when a quote is created in the admin. If a comment is provided in the form field "Order Comments", then this comment will be saved in `quote.customer_note`. The value of this field will also be copied to the `sales_order` and `sales_invoice` tables.

`customer_note_notify`

This table field is also used when a quote is created in the admin. If you check the form checkbox "Append Comments" (this depends on the checkbox "Email Order Confirmation"), then this boolean will be saved in `quote.customer_note_notify`. The value of this field will also be copied to the `sales_order` and `sales_invoice` tables.

N.B.: Using this field in the frontend seems not to conflict with the default Magento 2 usage in de admin. As a matter of fact, it seems well setup to use it this way.

Answer (score 1):

### As you can understand exact answer can give only magento core architect. I can share only my opinion.

Looks like magento don't use this field somehow. Most probably it was added on projecting stage and never used in magento (or used in old versions). In my practice I faced with such fields in other tables and used them for my own necessity.

In other words if you don't know add your own or use existing - I think better use this.